# Wrong activeElement in focus in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In IE11 *span* element is in a focus state (`document.activeElement` returns *span*), but it element hasn't tabindex attribute and shouldn't be in focus.

Works fine in Chrome and Firefox (after click in focus div element with tabindex attribute). The problem only in IE11. BTW, cannot reproduce this issue on the jsbin.

[image: example]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qdmJ.png

I also don't see span in a list of elements that can get focus.

Is it a known problem? How to make `div` with tabindex as an activeElement after clicking on the span?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536934.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found that it's unexpected behavior in IE11 and possible bug if span has `display: flex`. 
Chrome and Firefox after click on `span` return `div` and IE returns `span`.

Check snippet for details. Reported on caniuse and probably should be added to IE tracker.

```js
document.getElementById('d').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('active element is ' + document.activeElement);
});
```

```css
#d {
  display: flex;
}
span {
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id='d' tabindex="1">
  <div>
    <span>span</span>
  </div>
</div>
```